# How can I summon Charged Creepers

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I need a way to use **/summon** to summon a Charged Creeper but I don't know how.

Comment: It is already answered, but for your future tasks, just head to this page to generate summon commands: http://www.minecraftupdates.com/summon-command

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This should work:

```
/summon Creeper ~ ~ ~ {powered:1}
```

but be careful, without coordinates (`~ ~ ~`) it will spawn right on top of you!

Answer (score 2):

I just summon a creeper in creative of course and use /summon LightningBolt